# GeoDjango WebMapping Application Update

Tags: python, web-mapping, geodjango

According to the below GIS.SE questions, GeoDjango was the preferred framework for creating simple and quick webmap applications. But these questions are now all 2-3 years old.  Can we verify whether or not consensus says that GeoDjango still remains top among webmapping application frameworks?

[What are the advantages of using Rails for a GIS/mapping application?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14588/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-rails-for-a-gis-mapping-application/14602#14602)

[What are the Python tools/modules/add-ins crucial in GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23575/what-are-the-python-tools-modules-add-ins-crucial-in-gis/23581#23581)

[I'm new to GIS and I'm looking for a developer-friendly web GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/looking-for-a-developer-friendly-web-gis/13878#13878)

Comment: ##Is GeoDjango still alive? *Yes*
*At the time of writing: 2016-11-15* The GeoDjango [website is down](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/geodjango.org.html). However GeoDjango is a module of [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/) and both the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/geodjango) and [bug tracker](https://code.djangoproject.com/query?status=!closed&component=GIS&order=id) appear to still be active. ## Is GeoDjango *still* the *preferred* framework?
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯